# How to create a static local database to store data in my windows phone app?

Tags: database, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I want to store the data into my app locally and just read the data when the user searches. For example the flag and its country name.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you want to put a pre-populated db in your app there's some instructions here on how to include it and how to read from it:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh286411(v=vs.105).aspx

If that's not what you meant and you want to be able to read and write from a db in your app there's some links on that page too.

Comment: I want to store the data into the app at the time of designing only. User just searches the data. So help me in building the suitable database as stated in my question.

Comment: The link is the right one then. That's the instructions on MSDN for creating a Linq To SQL database that is distributed populated with your app.